# Unifying "this site is for..." descriptions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

After updating the FAQ, our 'this site is about...' description no longer matches the global SE site description (that has been with us since Area 51.) I would like to get all of them saying the same thing if possible as it feels a bit uneven to me.

The places where this would need to be changed:

- global SE "all sites" list has the original text
- area 51 has the original text

The text also gets displayed on remote sites when a question is migrated, etc., and I'm sure there are other nooks and crannies where the old description might be displayed.

Comment: What was the question again? Is it 'Should they be unified?' or 'which description should be the correct one?' or what?

Comment: @mitch pursuant to [Update the FAQ](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/171/update-the-faq-what-is-a-good-summary-for-this-site) a moderator had updated the FAQ text for the main site. I was hoping we could get the other places on SE where the original text was displayed updated to reflect our new 'this site is for...' text.

Answer (score 3):

So right now, you have:

> those interested in logical reasoning

...as the audience description (the text that appears next to your site on SE, on the About page, and elsewhere), and:

> philosophers, students of philosophy, and those interested in the history of ideas and the rational analysis of concepts

...in your FAQ. Is that the text you want in your audience description then? It's a *bit* lengthy - not a show-stopper, but if you could trim it down, you might be more happy with the final results.