# Can we modify the site's short description?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

At http://stackexchange.com/sites, the short description under Philosophy is "Q&A for those interested in logical reasoning". **I think this is somewhat misleading and diverts potential traffic away from us because people think the site is only about logic.** I use that /sites portal page to browse the SE sites fairly often, and I imagine others who use it could be thrown off by our description. Can we get this description changed?

This has been brought up before, and I provided alternative short description as well: https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171/update-the-faq-what-is-a-good-summary-for-this-site

Here are some ideas I offered:

> For those interested in the rational investigation of the truths and
>   principles of being, knowledge, or conduct.

or

> For those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of
>   knowledge, reality, and existence.

Comment: There was some [discussion on this here](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/223/unifying-this-site-is-for-descriptions) -- I raised the issue there since it seemed messy to say one thing in our FAQ, and something else on other spots on SE

Comment: I want to continue to push for this, as I think even these little changes over time can increase our numbers significantly.

Comment: Agree @stoicfury it looks like Joseph is working to aggregate some of the prior ideas. I have provided a new shell under a recently asked version of this one .. http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/3065/do-we-have-the-best-tagline-for-this-se

Comment: Yay, glad this was finally fixed. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upvote if you want to change it to:

> "For those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of
>   knowledge, reality, and existence."

Given that we have like 4 people that browse meta with any regularity, I imagine this will cap at like 3 votes... haha.

Please feel free to add your own answer if you want another wording!

Comment: I worry this emphasizes doing over studying philosophy, but that said this is significantly better than the existing text

Comment: True and true. I think "for those interested **in the study of** the fundamental nature..." ought to make it clear enough, and is certainly better than simply "for those interested the fundamental nature..."

Comment: Agreed. This is good for me

Comment: I like this. Sorry I haven't been around for a while. It's not perfect, but all I can think of are criticisms in the vein of what it might not include (to be fair, I primarily study continental philosophy). I don't have any particularly constructive suggestions, though, and it does seem an improvement over what we have now.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/sites was just changed to the new look, so I think having a better description is more important than ever! @RebeccaChernoff ;) :D

Comment: I am fine with this; definitely a major improvement

Comment: I still don't see what is wrong with 'For those interested in *philosophy*'...

Comment: I used this version. It might take a bit to propagate to the site listing, however.

Answer (score 13):

Is there some reason to avoid the word "philosophy" in the short description?

I mean, "Q&A for those interested in the discipline of philosophy" sounds reasonable to me.

In fact, "Q&A for those interested in the academic discipline of philosophy" sounds even better.

(My criteria for "better" in this context is one which would lead to more questions like [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/what-is-harmans-response-to-the-fake-barn-counterexample) and fewer like [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/1516/does-time-exist).)

Comment: I like this. It avoids the problem of trying to define philosophy within the short description and is nevertheless very clear.

Comment: I feel the way this particular short description is used around the site is more of a definition for the site, thus it seems strange to define 'philosophy' using the word itself. More importantly, I worry that the latter description in particular will dissuade some people from joining and asking questions which aren't rooted in a particular historical context but would otherwise be very valid here. Our site needs [*more* questions and *more* visits per day](http://bit.ly/drFfmu); at this point in time I think the description which is least restrictive/most inviting would be best to that end.

Comment: So I could live with the first one you provided (though I still prefer my own suggestion more), but I would personally be *against* the second one for including "academic", simply because questions involving novel concepts or otherwise not rooted in some historical text/figures views can still be valid here.

Comment: This seems rather circular.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is certainly possible.  The [last discussion](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/271/6) wasn't much of a discussion.  It was mentioned that the current audience might be a bit lengthy.  There weren't any responses to that.  Even a "might be lengthy, but it works".  It's just a matter of coming up with what the audience that works best and we'll get everything updated to match this time.

Comment: Yes, I think "For those interested in the study of the fundamental nature of knowledge, reality, and existence." is most encompassing while being quite short.

Comment: "for teachers and students of philosophy, and those interested in the history of ideas" might be another rendering

Comment: Right, so my point was...consensus!  People suggesting different things...not a consensus.  Figure something out together and then I'll change it.

Comment: @Joeseph: "history of ideas" seems too vague and makes it seem like this is a history website. Also, in some minor way the phrase "for teachers and students" might discourage people who aren't teachers or currently students (even though you meant it in a very liberal sense, "student of philosophy"), but that's not as big of a deal as the "history of ideas" part, imo.