# This site is about logic?

Tags: discussion

I did a search and found some overlapping discussions, but no specific answer to this question:  Why does the site description say "This site is for those interested in logical reasoning"?  That seems very narrow in comparison to both the full scope of philosophy and the actual content of the site.

Answer (score 2):

I and others been trying to change this for a long time:

[Can we modify the site's short description?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/can-we-modify-the-sites-short-description)

(It was actually deleted up until a second ago when I undeleted it; I'm not sure why @CodyGray deleted it in the first place as it was still an ongoing discussion in my mind, and clearly more and more people are recognizing this.)