# Appropriate slogan for philosophy

Tags: discussion, status-planned

I joined Philosophy forum the other day, and was surprised that this came out as the slogan for the forum:

*Q&A for those interested in logical reasoning.*

At this moment, I am not able to suggest better wording, but I know "logical reasoning" is not right. It sounds very restrictive to me. Philosophy is much wider term to me than "logical reasoning".

Would you agree with me?

If yes, what would be a better slogan for a philosophy forum?

*EDIT: Just to stress that I am not seeking another "scientific" definition of philosophy. Just a phrase that would (in a fairly accurate manner) describe what is philosophy about to your neighbor, or to a colleague, or to a person working in a store.*

*EDIT 2: I just discovered several similar threads on Philosophy Meta. This confirms that my uncomfortable feeling about slogan is justified.*

*EDIT 3: Please consider this question in a general sense, free of any politics, moderation, and similar. **How would you express essence of philosophy in a form of slogan?** So, I would like this question not to be voting for change, discussing forum improvements, etc etc. Just honest, free, intellectual discussion.*

Comment: I can't go into the library to find a book to answer your question. I can't point to any resources in order to answer the question. I can gather my feelings about it and dump it into the field below, but this is not what this site is about.

Comment: OK, if it turns out that there are more people that think like you, I will delete the question myself. However, I disagree with you. Ability to describe something in simple terms is rare, and actually requires very good understanding of the subject. I can't post this question in some general purpose forum, since it is not likely that somebody there will have good understanding of philosophy. That's why I think this forum is the right place for this question, and this question is the right question for this forum.

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind is that this is indeed not a forum, but a Q&A-site. That means that the questions should have answers. I don't think that yours has one or two, but thousands. And that none is correct, aswell. But then again, that is just me.

Comment: What is the best way to make scramble eggs? This question doesn't have thousand answers, most of the people would say it could have at most 3 or 4 answers.

Comment: Therefore: making scrambled eggs != philosophy?

Comment: You brought to my attention that this question may not be good for this site. I explained to you why I think it is good for this site. If you still don't like my question, and it makes you very uncomfortable, please vote it down, report it to moderators, or delete it if you are a moderator. Its that simple.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, many of us have wanted to change this for a while. Mods cannot do this, only admins can. When I raised this concern, they said we needed more consensus, which I suppose makes sense. But consensus to stackoverflow is like hundreds of upvotes, where we (with much less active meta participation) usually cap out at like 10 upvotes in agreement on the best of days, 3 or less on average. While I'm sure they take this into account, I'm sure it is not quite the consensus they are looking for and in general it is a low priority for them. On top of that, it doesn't help that we have 2 highly upvoted answers with almost the same amount of votes, so without a clear winner they have no way of deciding which to use.

Upvote this question **and the answer you like the most** to add to the consensus:
[Can we modify the site's short description?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/can-we-modify-the-sites-short-description)

Comment: Ok, I voted for, I guess, your suggestion, among the two. I would even delete "fundamental" out of it, but its not that crucial. Good luck!

Comment: I agree, fundamental could be removed; I think I originally worded it that way to really hone in on the fact that philosophy investigates down to the very core of our belief system, rather than focusing at the top (like the sciences, which rest upon many axioms and assumptions taken for granted).