# Description of Philosophy SE -- Why hasn't it been changed yet? Can we get it changed now?

Tags: discussion

Philosophy.SE's current short description is "Q&A for those interested in logical reasoning". I don't think this is a good description. The question of changing the description has already happened before [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277/can-we-modify-the-sites-short-description). Can we finally get it changed now?

Answer (score -2):

I'll post answer since I am not allowed to comment.

I think that description is fitting, and serves the community well.  Logical reasoning is *the* tool used by philosophers.  However, leadership here appears most interested in the history, identity, and ideas of philosophy than with the practice of philosophy.

So, in short, whoever created that description "Q&A for those interested in logical reasoning" was spot on.  However, by and large, this forum is not used to that end.